# Why doesn't PyTorch implicitly convert numbers and lists to tensors?

Tags: pytorch

Why doesn't PyTorch implicitly convert numbers and lists to tensors, when used with torch functions? For example

```
torch.exp([0, 1, 2])
```

errors out with

```
TypeError: exp(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list
```

Is it the overheads associated with creating a tensor, which Pytorch doesn't want to implicitly assume?

Comment: I feel like this question is off topic because it's not about a precise programming problem.

Comment: @Ivan So understanding the reasons why PyTorch was built a certain way isn't a programming problem? Is there a different forum you'd recommend?

Comment: In my opinion, including conversion makes a function too complex (determining the size of a given list, data type, etc.), which is not quite a good thing in the aspect of functional programming